# SQL trigger is not trigger after insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

```
CREATE TRIGGER xyz
ON abc
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
SET NOCOUNT ON;
AS
    DELETE FROM abc 
    WHERE condition;
```

The first time I insert records into table `abc` directly through the above script it works, but doesn't work when doing it through the application. Subsequently it works fine for both.

Why its not working first time when we run through the application? I tried the roll back option as well, with the same result. Anything wrong with the trigger?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That trigger seems to be product specific.)

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: No one but you knows what "does not work" means nor how you determine that it "does not work". It is far more concerning that you are deleting rows from a table within a trigger on that same table.

Comment: i need to delete future date records which are invalid records from table. There are some inserts happening from application which is pushing some invalid records with future date. so i have to identify those records from table when ever inserts happens.

Comment: any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the SET NOCOUNT ON within the block, after the AS

Comment: Tried and same result, its working when i insert records through automation scripts but not through application                                                                                         
CREATE TRIGGER xyz
ON abc
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE FROM abc 
    WHERE condition;

Comment: The trigger should be tied to the table, so it shouldn't be related to the application. I'd double check that the application is inserting or updating table abc. Also check that the WHERE condition isn't giving you a false negative.

Comment: am checking both after insert,update and where condition is also correct. where DateTime>GETDATE()

Comment: You may consider adding BEGIN and END to the block -- I don't think this will help you.

`CREATE TRIGGER xyz
ON abc
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE FROM abc 
    WHERE condition;

END`

Comment: Is the trigger enabled? Perhaps it is disabled and your automation scripts are giving you a false positive? 

`ALTER TABLE abc ENABLE TRIGGER xyx`

Comment: No change in result

Comment: Yes i ran that already no change in result, is there any better solution for this ?